# How to integrate ANTLR (2.7) in Visual Studio 2005 (C++) build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, antlr

I have a project containing files generated from a .g file (antlr 2.7.x). The guy who wrote the whole thing has left me with it. Until now, I did not need to modify the grammar and all was fine. But now, I cannot continue without modifying the grammar (i.e. the .g-file).

I have the source code of the used antlr and the visual studio 2005 project. Unfortunately, the lexer and parser files are not generated prior to the build (in fact they are never generated) and that leads to my question: how do I generate these files whenever the grammar file is modified? Or in other words, how do I integrate antlr into visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANTLR wiki has a few entries about Visual Studio integration:

- [VisualStudio C# Projects & C/C++ .rules Files for Visual Studio](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Integration+with+Development+Environments#IntegrationwithDevelopmentEnvironments-VisualStudio)
- [How do I make ANTLRWorks and Visual Studio work together?](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075)